# jupyter calling a shell function (not a shell command)

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, sh, jupyter

I have defined a function in my startup ~/.bashrc script.
And I can simply run that function from any Ubuntu terminal, once my machine is up and I am logged in.

However, when I try to execute this command in my jupyter notebook, it doesn't work, and I tried any combination of the following commands...

```
!myFunction
```

but this didn't work

I even tried this:

```
!source myFunction
```

But no matter what I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: myFunction: not found
```

Anyway to get around this error... ?!
By the way, all the predefined shell commands work just fine (e.g. ls/pwd/cd/...)

Comment: You seem to be talking about two different systems here. Are you?

Comment: Also, is that one script you're citing, or are they just three separate terminal/command-line commands.

Comment: @Roadowl. sorry for the conusion. All i meant to say, is that I tried all three of them seperately..... i will edit the questio

Comment: It seems that commands executed from jupyter doesn't ran in a shell. You can try !bash -c 'your_function'

Comment: @geckos I tried your suggestion...... but didnt' work.... couldn't recognize my function

Comment: You may try to run a script instead of a function. From the script you should have no problem calling the function.

Comment: Note that `source` receives a file as argument, not a function. I will execute the file in the same shell sessions that `source` was typed. If `!...` open a new shell session for each command `!source ...` will not work either

Comment: What happens if you try `!source .bashrc` (possibly adding the path where it exists) then `!myFunction`?